# Show layer information when cliclked on map in ArcGIS for Android

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis

Recently I have started working on ArcGIS for Android. In my application I am able to consume services created in ArcGIS.com and can display the map in the Android device. Now I want to get the layer information of the map when clicked on a perticular layer. There is not much info on ArcGIS resources. It would be greatful if anyone guide me how to get information with some examples if possible.
The code to show map is:

private MapView map = null;

String dynamicMapURL = "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer";

map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer dynamicLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(dynamicMapURL);
map.addLayer(dynamicLayer);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the samples provided by the ArcGIS API.

In the help of ArcGIS they explain how to use them and what each of one does.

Here is the link:

[Samples ArcGIS Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/#/How_to_work_with_samples/011900000007000000/)

Hope it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [IdentifyTask class](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/tasks/ags/identify/IdentifyTask.html). It works with dynamic map services.

The ArcGIS SDK for Android does have an IdentifyTask sample as part of the SDK plugin for Eclipse. With the plugin installed, in Eclipse, go to File > New > Other. Choose ArcGIS for Android > ArcGIS Samples for Android. Check the box for local samples, then choose Tasks > IdentifyTask.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is simple code snippet to identify and select an object on ArcGIS map feature layer using ArcGIS-Runtime v100.x Android SDK.**

MainActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.esri.arcgisruntime.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.data.ArcGISFeature;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.data.Feature;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.data.FeatureEditResult;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.data.FeatureQueryResult;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.data.QueryParameters;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.data.ServiceFeatureTable;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Envelope;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Point;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.ArcGISTiledLayer;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.FeatureLayer;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.ArcGISMap;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Basemap;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.DefaultMapViewOnTouchListener;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.GraphicsOverlay;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private MapView mMapView = null;
    private ArcGISMap mMap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMap = new ArcGISMap();
        mMapView.setMap(mMap);

        // Applying base map as tiled layer.
        final Basemap baseMap = new Basemap(new ArcGISTiledLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"));
        mMap.setBasemap(baseMap);

        final ServiceFeatureTable serviceFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("http://..feature-layer-full-url");
        final FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(serviceFeatureTable);
        featureLayer.setSelectionColor(Color.BLUE);
        featureLayer.setSelectionWidth(10);
        mMap.getOperationalLayers().add(featureLayer);

        final GraphicsOverlay overlay = new GraphicsOverlay();
        mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(overlay);

        mMapView.setOnTouchListener(new DefaultMapViewOnTouchListener(this, mMapView) {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

                android.graphics.Point screenPoint = new android.graphics.Point(Math.round(event.getX()), Math.round(event.getY()));
                Point scenePoint = mMapView.screenToLocation(screenPoint);

                int tolerance = 10;
                double mapTolerance = tolerance * mMapView.getUnitsPerDensityIndependentPixel();

                // create objects required to do a selection with a query
                Envelope envelope = new Envelope(scenePoint.getX() - mapTolerance, scenePoint.getY() - mapTolerance, scenePoint.getX() + mapTolerance, scenePoint.getY() + mapTolerance, mMapView.getSpatialReference());
                QueryParameters query = new QueryParameters();
                query.setGeometry(envelope);
                final ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future = featureLayer.selectFeaturesAsync(query, FeatureLayer.SelectionMode.ADD);

                // add done loading listener to fire when the selection returns
                future.addDoneListener(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            FeatureQueryResult result = future.get();
                            Iterator<Feature> iterator = result.iterator();
                            Feature feature;
                            int counter = 0;
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                                feature = iterator.next();
                                counter++;
                                Log.d(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "Selection #: " + counter + " Table name: " + feature.getFeatureTable().getTableName());
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), counter + " features selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            Log.e(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "Select feature failed: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.dispose();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> **NOTE**: This worked properly in Android Studio v3.x.x and Java 1.8.
>
> *build.gradle (Modue)*: `implementation 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.2.1'`
>
> *build.gradle (Project)*: maven {
>                  url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
>              }